# Style Top & Bottom Part of Divider for Tab Widget

Tags: android

[image]

I have a TabWidget and I'm trying to style the divider. (See image above)

I set the Divider Drawable of the TabWidget but the top & bottom part is unchanged. I can't figure out how to style it.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is set the `dividerPadding` attribute to `0dp` in your `TabWidget`.

`android:dividerPadding="0dp"`

Also, maybe consider switching to [ActionBar.Tabs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html) instead, just considering `TabWidget` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Holo theme has default 16 pixels dividerPadding for each TabWidget.
I try to set it to zero in the XML but it is not working.
Fortunately, it works for me to set it dynamically as below

> myTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerPadding(0);

Note: I am using android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about grey bars on the top and the bottom of the divider? use fill_parent for the drawable's height and width if that is the case!

Comment: Yes, the grey bars. However, I cannot set android:height of the drawable in the size tag to android:height="match_parent". Here's my drawable: https://gist.github.com/dannyroa/4ea2018836217b344806

Comment: how about removing the size tag at all and setting  layout_width and layout_height on the Widget referencing the drawable. this should work!